# Make a blank area clickable in android and then make an image appear over the area clicked

Tags: android, android-view

Can anyone tell me please how can I make the whole blank screen clickable on the android ? Means wherever I can click on it and then the place where i click there one particular image has to appear where i can then make the notes. I am trying to first find the coordinates of that area and then putting the image. But i am not able to find the code for doing that. Means after finding the coordinates what can be done?

Or if there is some other way then also please help with that!!

For finding coordinates:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView xCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView yCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    xCoord.setText(String.valueOf((int) event.getX()));
                    yCoord.setText(String.valueOf((int) event.getY()));
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
                    xCoord.setText(String.valueOf((int) event.getX()));
                    yCoord.setText(String.valueOf((int) event.getY()));
                    break;
                }
            }

            return true;

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Have an ImageView ready... make it invisible. When they click - set the coords of the ImageView to where they clicked AND make it visible :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an ImageView (or have one in your Layout)
2. Make sure it's invisible on initialisation
3. When the user clicks use the coordinates to set the location of the ImageView
4. Make the ImageView visible
5. Take a sigh of relief.

Comment: Thank you very much for this idea..but i just wanted to know that how can we place an imageview at the calculated coordinates??

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/16782705/android-setx-and-sety-behaving-weird

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes that link was of help and i was able to do it!!:)

Comment: Excellent! Do you think I could trouble you to tick the answer? All the best :)

Comment: In this what can i do if i want multiple images on my screen but only after a touchevent. I am able to achieve that for two images. Like one time i touch one image appears, another time i touch, another image appears, like this.

Comment: and yes then those images remain on the screen.

Comment: You will keep track on a global variable for the Activity how many times they have touched. Then in the event handler you see how many times they have already clicked then base the reaction on that.

Comment: Now, please - go ahead that click that tick! :)

Comment: yes but i am not able to implement this in code. Even if the global variable will keep track of the number of times it is touched then also, is placing an image not a different thing altogether? I want help with the code in this. I tried using getheight function. But in that it is possible only for two images. For more than that it is not working.

Comment: i used switch case to display the image using that gobal variable but the images are overlapping on each other. They should be on the position of the click.

Comment: @Gaur What do you mean overlap? So, you mean that they are not showing up depending on where you clicked?

Comment: yes!! Those images are displayed on each click but all at the same position, though i am calling the placeimage function every time the image needs to be displayed at given coordinates.

Comment: public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        int eventAction = event.getAction();
        switch(eventAction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                float TouchX = event.getX();
                float TouchY = event.getY();
                placeImage(TouchX, TouchY);
                mLastTouchX++;
                super.onTouchEvent(event);
                break;
        }

Comment: In this I have taken mLastTouchX as the global variable which gets incremented with every click. Then according to that i am using switch case

Comment: I see... maybe you could show the code of placeImage() as well?